# Container with char* key and int value

Tags: c++, dictionary, mfc, stdmap

I need a container in which i can store a `char*` key and `int` value.

I can use `std::map` and mfc `CMap` but i dont know few operation when using `char*` as key.

Something like below:

```
#include"iostream"
#include<map>
using namespace std;

std::map<char*,int>Mymap;
or
//Cmap<char*, char*, int, int>Mymap;

char* p = "AAA";
char* q = "BBB";

int p_val = 10;
int q_val = 20;

int main()
{
    // How to use insert, find and access keys      

    return 0;
}
```

I want to know both the solutions with `map` as well as `CMap`.

Comment: You'd save yourself a lot of trouble by using `std::string` instead. What's `CMap`? Doesn't seem to be part of C++.

Comment: CMap is the part of mfc `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s897094z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx` ..I have a char* key so i need to convert key in to `std::string` or `Cstring` if i will change the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Example how to use std""map with char* key and int value.

```
//Example of std::map with char* key and int as value.

#include"iostream"
using namespace std;
#include<map>

struct cmp_str
{
    bool operator()(char *first, char  *second)
    {
        return strcmp(first, second) < 0;
    }
};

typedef std::map<char*,int, cmp_str>MAP;
MAP myMap;

void Search(char *Key)
{
    MAP::iterator iter = myMap.find(Key);

    if (iter != myMap.end())
    {
        cout<<"Key : "<<(*iter).first<<" found whith value : "<<(*iter).second<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Key does not found"<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *Key1 = "DEV";
    char *Key2 = "TEST";
    char *Key3 = "dev";

    //Insert Key in Map
    myMap.insert(MAP::value_type(Key1, 100));
    myMap.insert(MAP::value_type(Key2, 200));


    // Find Key in Map
    Search(Key1);       // Present in Map
    Search(Key2);       // Present in Map

    Search(Key3);       // Not in Map as it's case sensitive

    myMap.erase(Key2);  // Delete Key2
    Search(Key2);       // Not in Map as deleted 

    return 0;
}
```

By Using MFC cmap also we can achieve the same but the operations might(functions) change.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that if you don't write your own comparator, stuff that will actually be compared by internal map functions are memory addresses of your char* elements. So, you would basically need your own comparator, which is not that hard to write. Or simply use `std::string` as key and whenever you need `char*` you just call `string.c_str()`.

Comment: Yes the above explanation is right but i needed only char* key that i have posted in a Answer now